# How to pass Webpack generated files to Gulp streams

Tags: javascript, gulp, webpack

Considering the following Webpack Gulp task, how can this be integrated with Gulp in such a way that after compiling Webpack pipes the files to Gulp so that I can run further tasks?

```
gulp.task('webpack', function(callback) {
  webpackCompiler.run(function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      throw new plugins.util.PluginError('webpack', err);
    }
    plugins.util.log('webpack', stats.toString({
      colors: true,
    }));
    callback();
  });
});

gulp.task('set-env-dev', function() {
  webpackConfig.plugins = [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin(info.name + '\n' + info.version + ':' + Date.now() + ' [development build]'),
    new ComponentPlugin()
  ];
  webpackCompiler = webpack( webpackConfig );
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is now a plugin for Gulp that allows deeper integration of Webpack and Gulp:
https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream